# PySimpleGUI - get some lists, then update the layout using "for"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I want to download 3 lists from 3 websites, then populate the layout (text) with that, but I'm getting trouble update, no problem downloading the lists.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

list_a, list_b, list_c = [], [], []

left_menu =  [
    [sg.Button("site_a")],
    [sg.Button("site_b")],
    [sg.Button("site_c")]
]

right_menu = []

layout = [
    [
        sg.Column(left_menu),
        sg.VSeperator(),
        sg.Column(right_menu)
    ]
]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = sg.Window("Events", layout=layout)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "site_a":
            list_a = download_from_site_a()
            #list_a = [dict(x=1, z=4, y=0), dict(x=36, z=7, y=2)]
            for a in list_a:
                right_menu += [[sg.Text(f"{a}", key="-A-")]]
                window["-A-"].update(a)
                window.Refresh()
        if event == "site_b":
            pass
        if event == "site_c":
            pass
    window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, there's only one method provided to expand the layout of a container by rows, `sg.Window.extend_layout`.

Demo code

```py
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg

left_menu =  [
    [sg.Button("site_a")],
    [sg.Button("site_b")],
    [sg.Button("site_c")],
]

right_menu = []

layout = [
    [sg.Column(left_menu),
     sg.VSeperator(),
     sg.Column(right_menu, expand_x=True, expand_y=True,
        scrollable=True,  vertical_scroll_only=True, key='right'),
    ],
]
window = sg.Window("Events", size=(640, 480), layout=layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "site_a":
        items = [dict(x=randint(0, 99), z=randint(0, 99), y=randint(0, 99)) for i in range(50)]
        new_rows = [[sg.Text(f"{item}", key=("-A-", i))] for i, item in enumerate(items)]
        window.extend_layout(window['right'], new_rows)
        window.refresh()
        window['right'].contents_changed()    # Update the content of `sg.Column` after window.refresh()

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I learned a lot from your help